# "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list" at the end of an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, devexpress, aspxgridview

I get this exception when button_click method is over.

The problem is that in this part of code i do not have any string format or something like this.

I can't understand why this is happening.

The button is in a popup form in a detail grid. The weird thing is that the record is update just fine.

Below is my code.

```
protected void ASPxButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime birth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(MONTH.Text));
        birth = birth.AddYears(-Convert.ToInt32(YEAR.Text));

        int key = 0;

        Prsnout_RootObject prsn = new Prsnout_RootObject();
        prsn.data = new PrsnData();
        prsn.data.PRSNOUT = new List<PRSNOUT>();
        prsn.data.PRSEXTRA = new List<PRSEXTRA>();
        prsn.data.PRSOUTEXTRA = new List<PRSOUTEXTRA>();

        if ((Session["newrecord"] != null))
        {
            if (!(Boolean)(Session["newrecord"]))
                key = Convert.ToInt32(Session["KEYROWPRSN"].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
        }

        prsn.data.PRSNOUT.Add(new PRSNOUT
        {
            CODE = (key == 0 ? "*" : null),
            NAME = ASPxTextBox4.Text,
            NAME2 = ASPxTextBox4.Text,
            CCCZOOSEX = Convert.ToInt32(ASPxComboBox1.Value),
            CCCRATSA = Convert.ToInt32(CCCRATSA.Value),
            CCCANIMAL = Convert.ToInt32(CCCANIMAL.Value),
            UPDDATE = (((DateTime)DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")),
            BIRTHDATE = (((DateTime)birth).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            CCCCHARACTER = Convert.ToInt32(CHARACTER.Value),
            CCCORIGIN = country.Text,
            CCCBREEDER = EKTROFEAS.Text,
            CCCFOOD = EIDDIATR.Text,
            CCCCHARACTERISTICS = IDIAITCHAR.Text,
            CCCBLOOD = Convert.ToInt32(AIMA.Value),
            CCCHISTORY = PAST.Text,

        }
        );

        double kj = Convert.ToDouble(WEIGHT.Text);


        prsn.data.PRSOUTEXTRA.Add(new PRSOUTEXTRA
        {
            BOOL01 = Convert.ToInt32(CROSS.Checked),
            VARCHAR05 = MICROCHIP.Text,
            NUM01 = WEIGHT.Text != "" ? WEIGHT.Text.ToString().Replace(",", ".") : "", //!= null ? int.Parse(WEIGHT.Text) : 0.0,
            CCCHM = (Convert.ToInt32(DIATROFI.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected)).ToString(),
            CCCDF = (Convert.ToInt32(DIATROFI.Items.FindByValue("2").Selected)).ToString(),
            CCCCF = (Convert.ToInt32(DIATROFI.Items.FindByValue("3").Selected)).ToString(),
            UTBL03 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["D"]),
            UTBL04 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["U"]),
            UTBL05 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DV"]),
            CCCCOLOUR1 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("GREY").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR2 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("RED").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR3 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("BROWN").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR4 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("WHITE").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR5 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("BLACK").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR6 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("MEL").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR7 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("BEZ").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR8 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("BLONDE").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR9 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("TIGER").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR10 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("APAL").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR11 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("PAL").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR12 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("STR").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR13 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("ISAV").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR14 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("ORED").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR15 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("ORMEL").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR16 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("ORF").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR17 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("IRON").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR18 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("RACE").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR19 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("FAIO").Selected),
            CCCCOLOUR20 = Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("VWHITE").Selected)

        }
        );
        string kkk = (Convert.ToInt32(COLOUR.Items.FindByValue("GREY").Selected)).ToString();

        Def.result r = (Def.result)ws.SetData(ResultLogin, "setdata", "PRSNOUT", "Κτηνιατρείο(2)(2)", key, prsn.data);

        if (ws.Error != null)
        {
            POST.HeaderText = "Error";
            ASPxLabel2.Text = ws.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            POST.HeaderText = "";
            ASPxLabel2.Text = "H καταχώρηση ολοκληρώθηκε.";
            ASPxPopupControl1.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        POST.HeaderText = "Error";
        ASPxLabel2.Text = ee.Message;
    }
    ASPxPopupControl1.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
    POST.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
    Session.Add("newrecord", false);

}
```

Comment: And where is the exception being thrown, when you debug the code?

Comment: My first guess is that Session["KEYROWPRSN"].ToString().Split(';') is not always producing an array of at least 2 strings.

Comment: It is thrown at the end of the event.. All the code of the event is executed just fine..